# mkfs.vfat: re-label existing filesystem?

Tags: linux, label

I have several USB sticks that were all made with `mkfs.vfat -n FOO` and I would like to re-label the filesystems without having to grab all the files on them, re-format, and put the files back on. Is there an option to mkfs.vfat I'm not seeing, or some other tool, that can do this?

Comment: Gparted can theoretically do it. [This forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1603044&page=2&p=12205241#post12205241) suggests that if you want a mixed-case label, you have to clear it with gparted, then do `sudo dosfslabel <device> <label>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `mlabel` program from the Mtools package.

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/html_node/mlabel.html):

> The `mlabel` command adds a volume label to a disk. Its syntax is:
>
>   ```
>   mlabel [-vcsn] [-N serial] drive:[new_label]
>   ```

Comment: Is drive the device node? so like mlabel /dev/sdd1:usbdrive?

Answer (score 5):

also you can do it by fatlabel

```
fatlabel /dev/device
```

gives you label

```
fatlabel /dev/device NEW_LABEL
```

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted. `fatlabel` (AKA `dosfslabel`) is the canonical name of the tool that is provided as part of `dosfstools`, which also includes `mkfs.fat`. No need for additional packages.